# Why do my ath9k generated RadioTap headers seems malformed?

Tags: linux-device-driver, scapy, radiotap

I'm collecting 802.11 packets using scapy on Ubuntu 16.04 (4.4 kernel). The RadioTap headers for my packets have the following present flags:

```
present=TSFT+Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext
```

Given the description of RadioTap, I would expect Channel to start on the 10th byte following the header and preceding fields (8 for TSFT + 1 each for Flags and Rate). Channel has an alignment of 2, so there is no need for padding. Yet this is what is in the undecoded portion of the packet:

```
notdecoded=' \x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00f\xc0 \x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xa9\x00\x00\x00\xa9\x00'
```

In this case the channel number actually appears at bytes 18-19 ('l\t' = 2412), and im not sure exactly what byte contains the dBm signal strength.

Anyone have an idea as to what i'm missing?

Comment: The `notdecoded` attribute for a packet I just sniffed is `'\xd5q\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xfa\x01\x00\x00'`, which makes sense since `notdecoded[10:12] = 'l\t'`. Can you please edit the question to include the full packet, rather than just the `notdecoded` part? What does wireshark display when fed with this packet?

Comment: I get those same results using my intel wireless cards, everything being in the right place. tcpdump is able to decode the packet, what i need for an answer here is someone who understands what those extra 8 bytes are. I will try to get on the system and grab a packet in a bit and will update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer after digging into the spec a bit deeper:

Scapy doesn't parse **extended headers** as signified by **bit-32** (though it did tell me about them by stating **+Ext** above). Those extra headers are stuffed on the front of 'notdecoded' section of the packet. I think scapy should, at minimum, remove those extended headers from not-decoded to avoid future confusion.

In this particular case there are two extra 32 bit extended bitmap headers, accounting for the extra 8 bytes.

If someone wants to write an answer up with more detail, ill accept it, otherwise i will clean this answer up and accept it for perpetuity.